# Variance of linear regression estimator

Tags: statistics, variance, linear-regression, parameter-estimation

Since $\hat{Y}$ is an estimator and given as a linear combination of estimators $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$ and X can be treated as a constant in simple linear regression,  is it correct that: $Var(\hat{Y}) = Var(\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}X)= 
Var(\hat{\beta_0})+X^2Var(\hat{\beta_1})+2XCov(\hat{\beta_0},\hat{\beta_1})$

-I see many books on Linear Regression talk of the variance of $\hat{Y}$ in the bias-variance discussion, but few texts describe the calculations of these terms.

Comment: Your notation is slightly confusing. You should also need a $x$ auxiliary variable along with the known value of $X$. Typically the regression estimator is stated something like $\hat{Y}=y+\beta(X-x)$

Comment: $Var(\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}X)=Var(\hat{\beta_0})+X^2Var(\hat{\beta_1})+2\color{blue}X Cov(\hat{\beta_0},\hat{\beta_1})$ is fine as long as $X$ is constant.